# Select in multiple tables using EFCore

Tags: mysql, asp.net-core, ef-core-2.1

I have the MySql tables schema below (resumed):

[image: Database Schema]

I need to Select only the category data in a Query using EFCore:

```
    List<CategoryViewModel> viewModel = await _context.Category
    .Join(_context.Product_Category, c => c.CategoryId, pc => pc.CategoryId, (c, pc) => new { c, pc })
    .Join(_context.Product, cpc => cpc.pc.ProductId, p => p.ProductId, (cpc, p) => new { cpc, p })
    .Where(cpcp => cpcp.p.EstablishmentId == paramEstablishmentId) //paramEstablishmentId comes via parameter
    .Select(vm => new CategoryViewModel()
    {
      Id = vm.cpc.pc.category.CategortId,
      Name = vm.cpc.pc.category.Name,
      Image = vm.cpc.pc.category.ImagePath,
      Description = vm.cpc.pc.category.Description
    })
    .ToListAsync();
```

But this query always result a list with zero models inside. I guarantee there are values in the database to be returned.

Any Ideia what i'm doing wrong?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @Flyzzx Answer (many thanks, friend), i've modify my query to:

```
  List<CategoryViewModel> viewModel = await _context.Product_Category
    .Where(pc => pc.Product.EstablishmentId == EstablishmentId)
    .Include(pc => pc.Product)
    .Include(pc => pc.Category)
    .Select(c => new CategoryViewModel()
    {
      Id = c.Category.Id,
      Name = c.Category.Name,
      Image = c.Category.ImagePath,
      Description =  c.Category.Description
    }).Distinct()
    .ToListAsync();
```

Basically, instead of select Categories, now i select Product_Category and use Include to add Products and Categories, making possible to use the Where Clause.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `Include()`function instead of join. For eg :

```
var blogs = context.Blogs
    .Include(blog => blog.Posts)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for awnser me, but what about the Where Clause? How can i Access the Category where the product's EstablishmentId equals to Establishment's Id?

Comment: You can chain the methods like this : `context.Blogs.Include(blog => blog.Posts).Where(c => c.Id == Another_Id).ToList();`